# Incredibly bad upload speed towards my IP only

Tags: networking, virtualbox-networking, upload, download-speed

I'm running a VDS (Virtual Dedicated Server)  on Ubuntu 16.04. I'm experiencing a very bizarre issue with uploading. Let me try to explain, by using a "map".

- VDS --> My Local PC = Upload speed is more or less 0.5mbps.
- VDS --> GitHub = Extremely fast upload speed.

Of course, logically you would assume that my internet connection is terrible. However this is not the case, I have 100/100 with about 30 ping towards the VDS.

So, I thought to myself, how else could I ensure that this is not actually just my connection. So I tried yet another step.

- VDS --> GitHub --> My Local PC = Extremely fast upload/ download speed.
- VDS --> My friends Local PC = Extremely fast upload speed.
- My Local PC --> VDS  = Extremely fast upload speed.

So, basically, the VDS/Linux is having extremely terrible upload speeds towards my SPECIFIC IP.

This is a massive problem as I am running a game server, and I'm the lead developer of said server. Whenever I try to connect to my game server and download its content this process literally takes 1 hour per 0.01MiB, which is ridiculous.

Does anyone out there have any idea how I could possibly fix this issue?

Comment: Can you check behaviour from a different customer of the same ISP as you? This is probably not a Ubuntu problem, but rather a problem somewhere in the path between you and your server.

Comment: Where is the VDS running? I am not sure if it is running in a VM on your local machine or somewhere else. Where is your friend's "local PC"? Is it on the same network as yours? Are these transfers going over the internet or over a local LAN?

Comment: @terdo

I've done a lot of testing today. Here is most of everything I found.

The VPS is located in UK (Bristol).
I am located in Spain.
Friend 1 is located in Belgium.
Friend 2 is located in Portugal.
Friend 3 is located in UK (London).

VPS --> Friend 1 = 20mbps.
VPS --> Friend 2 = 20mbps.
VPS --> Friend 3 = 0.02-0.5mbps.
VPS --> Me = 0.02-0.5mbps.

Me and friend 3 both have really good connections and will get the same speed as everyone else if we download from anywhere apart from my specific VPS. (We do not have the same provider)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include these details.But with what you describe, I don't see how it can be related to Ubuntu.